# Why I can't send cookies to the website with Scrapy or Selenium?

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, scrapy

First of all, please forgive me if my question has a very obvious solution. I am new to web scraping and Scrapy. This will be my third website to be scrapped(If I can find a solution to the following problem).

**What I am trying to achieve:**

is to scrape the product data from the following website: https://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/sclist/30011-tum-meyveler

**however**
products load dynamically according to the city-district you choose after you logged in.

So I thought, maybe I can log in with my own account, grab the cookies from the Request Headers and send them with scrapy Request. The problem, I guess, the website does not accept the cookies I have sent.

I also tried the same procedure with selenium.

1. opened the page
2. logged in
3. choosed the city
4. got the cookies(also save them with pickle to later use on scrapy but didn't work)
5. delete all cookies from website
6. send the cookies in the step 4 after refreshing the page

again website did not accept cookies.

**Note**: Since I need to scrape all categories in the website on a daily basis I need a fast scraping solution like scrapy. So scraping with Selenium is not an option for me.

Here are some logs and screenshots to support my problem.

[Request url and method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmm5F.png)

[Request headers and cookie info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2uSC.png)

[data preview after I logged in and choose a city(note the 'sid:1885' this is the store id that I want to scrape)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCrNo.png)

[this is the output of view(response) line from scrapy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/967Nu.png)

```
scrapy shell https://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/sclist/30011-tum-meyveler
from scrapy import Request
mycookie = {'JSESSIONID ': 'yndMqXswzQYeUw1CsLtp9A0GBI7ZZE0yI1W0zPk4u4JJxpZES8RF!-1577658491 ', 'NSC_wjq_dt_iuuq_lbohvsvn_lxfc    ': '756ca3c16479c6cdde0681fa2edb1040d4786c1c0a6b2f3116d5fc7f605b4631d4d0f199 ','_dc_gtm_UA-1547459-1  ':'1','_ga':'GA1.3.219867582.1525198968','_gat_UA-1547459-1 ':'1','_gid':'GA1.3.1499846526.1525198968','current-currency    ':'TRY','customer':'ggB2MTVRWi76tWJwj2ZvbDa896G27N3YaH','district':'ac00a4001701ce63cc30626def','first-permission-impression    ':'1','ins-gaSSId   ':'cbf3cd92-3c71-e321-30ac-b2d89dbf3826_1525528747  ','insIsUserLoggedIn    ':'1','insTotalCartAmount187    ':'194.96   ','insUserDetails   ':'%22muharrem.akkaya96%40gmail.com%22  ','insdrSV':'285','scs':'%7B%22t%22%3A1%7D  ','spUID':'15251989688268402d4dc11.7edd9701 ','total-cart-amount    ':'120.78   '}
req = Request('https://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/getProductList.do?shopCategoryId=30011',cookies = mycookie)
fetch(req)
view(response)
```

Log for the first line

```
2018-05-05 19:11:02 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: seleniumcrawler)
2018-05-05 19:11:03 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.9.0, Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.16299
2018-05-05 19:11:03 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'COOKIES_DEBUG': True, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'seleniumcrawler.spiders', 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['seleniumcrawler.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'seleniumcrawler', 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0, 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36', 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8'}
2018-05-05 19:11:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2018-05-05 19:11:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'seleniumcrawler.middlewares.seleniumcrawlerDownloaderMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-05-05 19:11:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-05-05 19:11:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['seleniumcrawler.pipelines.JsonPipeline',
 'seleniumcrawler.pipelines.CsvPipeline']
2018-05-05 19:11:03 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-05-05 19:11:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-05-05 19:11:03 [migros] INFO: Spider opened: migros
2018-05-05 19:11:04 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Received cookies from: <200 https://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/sclist/30011-tum-meyveler>
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=cMTfOnFTK1dPSPF2Qdi0d1EqqCXP3HW0S00BwxOwljYjaOMcAOqE!1083904106; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: NSC_wjq_dt_iuuq_lbohvsvn_lxfc=0933a3df2cf252c6b4bd9a5784157b04f2a0c6e4b29bff73d54a79d474fdc48e85bdc9ec;path=/;secure;httponly
```

Log for the remaining lines

```
2018-05-05 19:19:32 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Sending cookies to: <GET https://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/getProductList.do?shopCategoryId=30011>
Cookie: customer=ggB2MTVRWi76tWJwj2ZvbDa896G27N3YaH; insIsUserLoggedIn=1; insUserDetails=%22muharrem.akkaya96%40gmail.com%22; district=ac00a4001701ce63cc30626def; spUID=15251989688268402d4dc11.7edd9701; ins-gaSSId=cbf3cd92-3c71-e321-30ac-b2d89dbf3826_1525528747; insTotalCartAmount187=194.96; _ga=GA1.3.219867582.1525198968; JSESSIONID=yndMqXswzQYeUw1CsLtp9A0GBI7ZZE0yI1W0zPk4u4JJxpZES8RF!-1577658491; current-currency=TRY; first-permission-impression=1; insdrSV=285; _gid=GA1.3.1499846526.1525198968; _gat_UA-1547459-1=1; total-cart-amount=120.78; _dc_gtm_UA-1547459-1=1; scs=%7B%22t%22%3A1%7D; NSC_wjq_dt_iuuq_lbohvsvn_lxfc=756ca3c16479c6cdde0681fa2edb1040d4786c1c0a6b2f3116d5fc7f605b4631d4d0f199; NSC_wjq_dt_iuuq_lbohvsvn_lxfc=0933a3df2cf252c6b4bd9a5784157b04f2a0c6e4b29bff73d54a79d474fdc48e85bdc9ec; JSESSIONID=cMTfOnFTK1dPSPF2Qdi0d1EqqCXP3HW0S00BwxOwljYjaOMcAOqE!1083904106
2018-05-05 19:19:32 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Received cookies from: <200 https://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/getProductList.do?shopCategoryId=30011>
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ZvvfjByrDdrOTwmJX7QaaU0jWBv5nxKgfXvPVfvwSsCn63bkGH3m!-1577658491; path=/; HttpOnly
2018-05-05 19:19:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/getProductList.do?shopCategoryId=30011> (referer: None)
```

So how can I overcome this cookie situation?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies seem to be sent correctly via your Scrapy code, and as far as I see, the problem is with your cookie value for the key `JSESSIONID`.

When I create my own session, set my city as "AFYON-Akmescit" and get that session ID, I get the `sid` `1885` for AFYON-Akmescit as expected, but when I try yours or any other corrupted session id (corrupt by changing one character randomly), I receive `sid` `193`. So somehow, the city id `193` is default and it does not accept your `JSESSIONID` value, not the cookie information itself.

Anyway, as another aspect of answer to your question, you should certainly not use session ID as a reliable source of identification while scraping, you might want to automatize the authentication process as well.